# Checking if a String contains a letter

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to check if all the Strings from my ArrayList contain a letter "L".

If yes - than the string should have been removed.

I wonder why not every string with "L" was removed?

The result is:

```
Rose
Leier
Rose
Rose
Rose
```

Code:

```
list.add("Leier");
list.add("Rose");
list.add("Liebe");
list.add("Leier");
list.add("Leier");
list.add("Rose");
list.add("Leier");
list.add("Rose");
list.add("Leier");
list.add("Rose");
list.add("Leier");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).matches(".*[L].*")) {
            list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than a regex to check for a single character, why not ``list.get(i).contains("L");``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an item from a list, it shifts all the remaining items towards the front of the list. So let's say you remove the item at index `5`: now the item at index 6 shifts to the position of 5, and 7 to 6, and so on.

After removing the item you increment `i`, so next you examine index 6. But **index 6 contains the item that used to be in index 7** - you've skipped over an item!

There are several ways to fix this. One is using the higher level `removeIf` method.

```
    list.removeIf(item -> item.matches(".*[L].*"));
```

Another is using an `Iterator` to iterate over the list, and remove items.

```
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String item = iterator.next();
        if (item.matches(".*[L].*")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

A third is *reversing the order of iteration*: if you iterate starting from the back of the list, changes to the list indices don't affect you.

```
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (list.get(i).matches(".*[L].*")) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

By the way, if you really only need to check if a string contains the letter `L`, it's easier to use the `contains` method instead of `matches`:  `item.contains("L")`

Comment: Thank you Joni for the explanation! It worked with iterator :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, don't forget to make it lower case

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().contains("l")) {

                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are no lower-case 'L' characters in the input, and even if there were, one should rather use `equalsIgnoreCase();`.

Comment: different thinking logic no more than that :)